# InfoPath 2010 Form Library data > Excel 2010 workbook

Tags: sharepoint, excel-2010, infopath2010, infopath-forms-services

I have a SharePoint 2010 server which I'm using to host a document library containing InfoPath forms. The forms are saving as XML files to the library and can be opened and viewed as completed "Forms".

I've connected the library to Excel 2010 using the "Export to Excel" details , and can refresh the data to pull down new form information however it only pulls down the name of the form and column headings for the library (which i guess it would as I've not changed any settings)

How do I go about setting this up to download the completed form data into a new row in the excel sheet?

e.g

> User Completes Form >> Completed form is uploaded to SharePoint >> Tracking
>   sheet is opened in excel >> New data is downloaded and added from the form library

Comment: aer you talking about user completing a form in the sense of creating a new form, or is the user using a form to enter data into a list?

Comment: Sorry, The user completes the form online, submits it (which saves the completed from to my library). from here i want to pull the information from all of the completed forms into excel.

Comment: It is still unclear what you are asking. Forms do not hold information in SharePoint. Forms are just masks for the user. Are you talking about list data or the form files themself?

Comment: The form files themselves need to be held as individual files (in this example the master .xsn file and user completed .xml files) for our record purposes. 

The data in the library is held inside these completed XML files, which are saved each time a user completes the master form inside his/her browser.

I would like to the connect excel to the library, and download the information to an excel workbook that acts like a tracker (not my idea , but again an unchangeable process)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kv8QtnovuyY - this is an example of what i want to do

Comment: Apologies , incorrect link supplied in the above post, I've edited now to correct it